# GORM Golang getting date only from created_at and get to my html

Tags: sql, database, go, httprequest, go-gorm

I want to put date without timezone in html. I want use created_at column to get my date.
But when I tried always like this '2022-10-19T00:00:00Z'.

This is my models

```
type Video struct {
    gorm.Model
    Id          int    `form:"id" json:"id" validate:"required"`
    Video       string `form:"video" json:"video" validate:"required"`
    Tumb        string `form:"tumb" json:"tumb" validate:"required"`
    Title       string `form:"title" json:"title" validate:"required"`
    Description string `form:"description" json:"description" validate:"required"`
    DisableAds  bool   `gorm:"default:false"`
    // UserIdVideo uint   `gorm:"foreignKey:UserIdUserIdVideo"`
}
```

This my html

```
        <div>
                    <center>
                        <p>
                            <video autoplay width="630" height="100%" controls>
                                <source src="/public/Video/{{.Videos.Video}}">
                            </video>
                        </p>
                    </center>
                    <h1>{{.Videos.Title}}</h1>
                    <p>{{.Videos.CreatedAt}}</p
                    <hr size="10px">
                    <b><p class="card-text">Creator Name</p></b>
                    {{.Videos.Description}}
                </div>
```

So I dont know how to get only date to appear in my web.